# How to create combinations avoiding permutations in python?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation

I'm trying to figure out which module can help me to avoid permutations when creating the combinations.

Say I have a dataframe of a single column: `pd.DataFrame({'composite_id':[1,1,1,2,3]})`

When I appply either permutations from itertools or multiset_permutations from sympy to it, to have a list of all possible combinations of 2, I get:

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[2,1],[2,3],[3,1],[3,2]]
```

And what I want is:

```
[[1,2],[1,3],[2,3]]
```

So as to avoid permutations of what I already have.

Is there a way to handle this?

Maybe some modules that allow checking this on the go?

Thanks in advance.